# Volley server issue

Tags: android, http-post, android-volley, android-networking

I am running an api which working fine on Postman, but when i am running it thru volley it giving me Server error.

> Response: com.android.volley.ServerError

Postman working fine:

[image]

**Code:**

```
  public  void postNewComment(Context context){
                    String url =     public static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.haebix.in/v1/register";

            RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);
            StringRequest sr = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Log.d(TAG,response.toString());

                }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("Error.Response", error.toString());

                }
            }){
                @Override
                protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("signup_type", "normal");
                    params.put("name", name);
                    params.put("email", emailID);
                    params.put("password", password);
                    params.put("mobile_no", phoneNo);
                    params.put("promo_code", promocode);
                    params.put("dob", "");
                    params.put("gender", "");
                    params.put("address", "");
                    params.put("city", "");
                    params.put("state", "");
                    params.put("pincode", "");
                    return params;
                }

                @Override
                public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
                    return params;
                }
            };
            queue.add(sr);
        }
```

Please help me to find my mistake.

Comment: Try using `getBody` instead of `getParams`

Comment: @BNK same error .Server with status code 400

Comment: Inside `getHeaders` use `params.put("Content-Type","application/json");` instead of `params.put("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");`

Comment: `String url =     public static final String BASE_URL = "http://api.haebix.in/v1/register";` What's this? what is your actual url? `url` or `BASE_URL` variable should be used?

Comment: @BNK thats typo mistake. The actual url is after Base url.

Comment: In the postman screenshot, it's the same as BASE_URL. But in your request, you use url

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite url as below:
String url = "http://api.haebix.in/v1/register";

I am getting response : 
{"error":false,"api_key":"b020bcc9a20c714f2e61c971a9ccd24c","message":"You are successfully registered"}

Answer (score 0):

RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

add this line before following on

queue.add(sr)

so it becomes

RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context);

queue.add(sr)

Might it help out